# Oveflow even when an int is mod by 10^9+7

Tags: c++, int, overflow

I wrote the following code for factorial of a number :

```cpp
long int fac[max+1];
    fac[0]=1;


    for(int j=1;j<=max;j++)
        {
            fac[j]=(fac[j-1]*j)%1000000007;
        }


    //Printing
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            cout<<fac[N[i]]<<"\n";
        }
```

This works perfectly for long int but we get a wrong answer if we change the array to int.

Please tell me why this is happening when range of int is greater than 10^9+7.

Comment: Do note that `long int` is the same as `int` in Windows.  If you want a guaranteed 64 bit type use `int64_t` or `long long` if you are okay with the type being at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that 0 ≤ `fac[j - 1]` < 10<sup>9</sup> + 7. But `fac[j - 1] * j` will be up to `j` times greater than that, and `long` is occasionally only 32-bit long (Windows). The absolute maximum value you can fit into a 32-bit number is 4294967295, only about four times your modulus.

Consider using `unsigned long long` instead of `long int` - that should work until `j` > 2<sup>34</sup>.

In fact, given that `(a * b) % N` is [mathematically equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488529/prove-that-ab-mod-n-a-mod-n-b-mod-n) to `(a % N) * (b % N)`, *once you have replaced `long int` with `unsigned long long`* you can rewrite

```
fac[j] = (fac[j - 1] * j) % 1000000007
```

to

```
fac[j] = (fac[j - 1] * (j % 1000000007)) % 1000000007
```

Then, because 1000000007<sup>2</sup> < 2<sup>64</sup>, you should be able to continue this on forever (although you will eventually run out of space for `fac`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

with `int fac[max+1];`, `fac[j-1] * j` is `int * int` with results in `int`.

if you overflow, you have UB and even with unsigned, you would lose data.

with `long int fac[max+1];`, then `fac[j-1] * j` is `long int * long int` (`int` -> `long int` for `j`) with results in `long int`.